# Dynamically insert version into heading

Tags: python-sphinx

I would like to insert dynamically the version into heading in the built docs, just like the next image but can't find a way to do it.

[image: Sphinx documentation with dynamic version in heading]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was now able to do it. In my Sphinx conf․py, defined a value:

```
version = “VALUE_I_WANT”
```

Then, to include it in the built docs, added in the header:

```
TITLE_I_WANT |version|
```

[Read more about |version| here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#substitutions).